# Can I create a list of elements based on different chain of characters from a string in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to create a list from a string by separating it by multiple chain of characters.
For example, I have the three strings as bellow:

```
a = "~O~O~O~OP"
b = "PO~O~~OO~"
c = "~O~O~O~OP~O~OO~"
```

I would like to create a list that would separate the "P", the "~O" and the "O~" in the right order.
It would so give me:

```
list_a = ["~O","~O","~O","~O","P"]
list_b = ["P","O~","O~","~O","O~"]
list_c = ["~O","~O","~O","~O","P","~O","~O","O~"]
```

As you can see, the lecture has to be done from the beginning of the string until the end and avoiding double reading.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2):

A simple pattern that express the 3 possibilities works nicely

```
import re

a = "~O~O~O~OP"
b = "PO~O~~OO~"
c = "~O~O~O~OP~O~OO~"

ptn = re.compile(r"(P|~O|O~)")

print(ptn.findall(a))  # ['~O', '~O', '~O', '~O', 'P']
print(ptn.findall(b))  # ['P', 'O~', 'O~', '~O', 'O~']
print(ptn.findall(c))  # ['~O', '~O', '~O', '~O', 'P', '~O', '~O', 'O~']
```

Answer (score -1):

A possible way could be to iterate over the string like this:

```
# Iterate over index
for element in range(0, len(string_name)):
    print(string_name[element])
```

I assume you know the "chain of characters", or to be more precise, the different substrings that you want to receive.
While iterating, you can just check every (pair of) character(s) for every substring, that you might want to obtain. So, for instance:

```
listA = []

for char in range(0, len(string)):
    if (char.equals(substring):
        listA.append(char)
    #to check for substrings with different lengths just check out every                 #possibility starting with the substring with the lowest length (in your example, P)
    if (char + string[char + 1]).equals(substring):
        listA.append(char + string[char + 1]
```

So you cann add your different substrings in the right order to one list and return it when the for loop is done.
I just coded it in here and maybe there are some syntactic errors, but it should work out that way.

Comment: Did you try that code regrading the given example ?

Comment: No, I did not try it, like said in my answer I just typed it in here fast to give an idea of how a solution could work. Your solution does seem much nicer though.

Comment: Because it does NOT do what the person ask for